# Wordpress version quick check?

Tags: widgets, dashboard

This should be a FAQ but I didn't find it quickly. Logging into my wordpress site as admin on the upper left and lower right it reminds me to upgrade to 4.2.1. This support topic on wordpress.org says it [should be in the dashboard](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-check-which-version-of-wordpress-is-installed) using the Right Now widget but I don't see the widget. Where can I quickly find my current wordpress version?

Comment: Right Now widget was renamed to At A Glance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the only one with this problem. The simplest way I feel is the site wide readme.html method or the wp-admin/about.php method.

This wordpress post has [four ways to check](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/why-so-difficult-to-find-the-wordpress-version-number) and this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390255/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-wordpress-is-running) had good info. I looked and looked but couldn't see it in the At a Glance box until later since the top and bottom already were both telling me to upgrade to a newer version.